# How can I open files in directories below the working directory in Jupyter with Python on Linux?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am an intermediate Python and Jupyter developer, but I am having an issue with what should seem a simple problem.

**Problem**

When I open a notebook and call the rsf package command to input a file, I cannot read rsf files in a given directory below the working directory. All files are not empty.

```
with rsf.input(fname) as sf:
```

The error is: FileNotFoundError returned by the following line:

```
with(open(filename, 'r') as fh:
```

**Attempted Solutions**

1) I have used `sys.path.append('/ <path from Jupyter working directory to file directory> /`), but still cannot read the files in that directory.

2) I have deleted the above `sys.path.append(...)` command and called `sys.path.pop()` to remove the file directory, and still have the same error.

3) I printed the sys.path to confirm and see that only python36 related directories are on the path, no custom directories I have added. I checked this after step 2.

4) I listed all files in the directory I specified, and I can see all expected files:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
mypath = <path from Jupyter working directory to file directory>
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
print(onlyfiles)
```

Is there another working directory path that I need to load?

Comment: Can you add your code..?

Comment: Cannot add all of it. The os.chdir(...) is working for me. Would help to find a reference explaining how sys and os paths are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `os.listdir` to see what files are visible to Python.

Also be aware that `open` [doesn't use](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) `sys.path`:

> file is a path-like object giving the pathname (absolute or relative to the current working directory)

You can change the 'current working directory' using `os.chdir`.

You can see the current directory using `os.path.abspath('.')`.

Comment: I used os.listdir to see files that Jupyter could find in this directory, and I see all the files, both ones I can and cannot read. I should have added that to my original attempts. I may use os.chdir in the active cell to change it and then change it back. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some more context here for sys.path vs os.path.

sys.path is used to change the path that Python searches to import packages: https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html

os.path is used to change the current working directory:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-chdir-method/